# Catching a save event globally in a datastore in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I have an application with a number of data stores in a number of different xpages and cc's. I'd like to catch all events when one of those are saved for logging and some other stuffs (it is not just logging). Is there a global "save data store"-event that I might subscribe to? I can find all those data stores and add a script in every querySaveDocument and so on but that is tedious and I will miss some. 

Is there a way to catch that event in one spot?

Comment: Hm, my first thought: NO. But maybe there is a way. Be more specific what is your "stuff" you want to do. You can think about DOTS (hack to document saves at server's API level) or some sort of Java injection in XSP engine.

Comment: I'd like to send changes to documents to an external system. In a workflow app some changes must be sent (via a java api) to another system and I'd like a simple way to catch all those changes without needing to find every save, because I'll miss some for sure.

Comment: You might modify this http://files.dontpanic82.com/EventsSSJS.txt to bind SSJS code to querySaveEvent for all DominoDocumentData sources. This is the related blog post: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.de/2010/03/xpages-dynamically-binding-document.html .

Comment: Thanks Knut. Its a good idea, I'll probably go with something like that.